# Cambiar el color de fondo de una celda seleccionada en un QTableWidget

Tags: pyqt5

Estoy trabajando con un elemento `QTableWidget` y necesito que el color de fondo de una celda al seleccionarse no aparezca, si no que en vez de ello se colore el margen de la celda seleccionada.

He intentado agregar la opción desde el editor de interfaces de Qt pero no obtengo ningun resultado.

Código:

```
QTableWidget:tem:selected:focus{
border:5px solid red;
background:none;
}
```

Esa es la propiedad que he tratado de agregar en la hoja de estilo para que elimine el fondo, pero no funciona.

Hay alguna manera de hacer esto desde una hoja de estilos `qss` o desde código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo imagen de la parte que necesito eliminarle el fondo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para colorear el fondo de un item seleccionado se usa la propiedad: `selection-background-color` posteriormente se indica el color de fondo que se desea tener.

En el caso de no necesitar un fondo de color solido este debe indicarse con el canal alfa al 0%, por lo que obtendremos un resultado como el siguiente:

```
QTableWidget{
   selection-background-color:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
```

Esta información se encuentra en la documentación

[QTableWidget StyleSheet Reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)
[selection-background-color](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#selection-background-color-prop)

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que necesitas es

```css
QTableWidget:item:selected:focus{
border : 2px solid  rgb(0, 255, 255);
color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /*Color a la letra*/
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.